# Modelica.Media: Using trace components

Tags: modelica

I am trying to get the hang of trace components and how to use them in the context of Modelica.Media and Modelica.Fluid. I am currently working on a multi-component media where a couple of the components are present in minute amounts, i.e. not important for the fluid's bulk properties. On the other hand, these components undergo (chemical) reactions, and it is thus essential that they are included in the mass balances in a sound way in order to account for this behaviour.

I wanted to model these as trace components, but I could not quite figure out how to implement these components in the context described above. More specific, I could not figure out how to have the mass (fraction) of a trace component vary due to model-internal reactions or model-internal mass transfer. It seems to me that the mass fractions of the trace components are meant to be constant in a given media - am I right?

Currently, all components of my media (including the ones in minute amounts) are included as "normal" components, as I could not manage to make the trace components behave the way I needed them to. As I am making the media more or less form scratch anyway I figured that I could just omit the components present in small amounts when giving the equations for calculating the fluid properties. Does anyone have any experience with modeling media components in trace amounts this way?

If anyone could elaborate on the difference between normal components and trace components, and/or give some advice about whether or not trace components would be the best way to model the above system, I would be very thankful. Any help or comments will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was on vacation and this one slipped by me.  Although I haven't been too actively involved in the most recent fluid design activities, I think you are correct in your understanding of what the "trace components" dimensions are for.

I'm assuming that the fluid library assumes that the trace components are inert in all the standard library components so I would not expect to see the trace components changing.  But I don't see why it would not be possible to create components that included reactions.  It will depend on whether your reactions occur "in a volume" (where you need to consider things like mixing, transport delay, etc) or whether they simply occur "on the fly" in the flow.  But either way, it should certainly be possible to formulate components where the in-flow and out-flow of trace components are not identical (which sounds like your concern).

Do you have any example code you could show of the issues you are facing or questions you have about the design of the trace components interface?

Again, sorry for the late response.